# AWS Service for custom feature?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I have begun working with AWS recently - very much a newbie and finding my way. I am looking for an approach with it to convert html in to pdf's. Are there any native services provided by AWS that do such as part of their offering? As alternative approaches I have also considered is using a lambda function to do such or work with EC2 or ECS with a .net library to do the conversion. Any guidance on what AWS can provide on this topic?

Comment: use a lambda and write whatever code is necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no built-in service in AWS for this.

As you've suggested, Lambda would be the ideal choice. No need to go for an EC2 or ECS solution.

A quick search of Google suggests that there are a number of Lambda based open source projects already out there, which do exactly what you want, or you could write your own if you prefer.

Answer (score 1):

AWS does not have any service that converts html to pdf. In order to make a Lambda function perform this use case, you would need to hook into a 3rd party API. There are various 3rd party APIs that perform this task. '